# analyze time-series consine similarity matrices (in R)

Tags: r, time-series, cosine-similarity

I have calculated the cosine similiarity between multiple users for 10 years separately. 
I can visualize and cluster the matrix of each year but I was wondering if there is a smart approach, vignette etc. how I can get into that topic. 
I think e.g. it could be interesting to see if influential users can be identified or if new clusters occur over time.

```
Year 1
       user1  user2  user3 ... 
user 1     1    0.2    0.5
user 2   0.2      1    0.1
user 3   0.5    0.1      1
...

Year 2
       user1  user2  user3 ... 
user 1     1    0.3    0.1
user 2   0.3      1    0.4
user 3   0.1    0.4      1
...
```

Comment: One of popular methods to analyze visually a lot of distance matrices at once is Weighted MDS aka INDSCAL.

Comment: Thank you @ttnphns! I'm not only interested in visualization but also in analyses and methods.

Comment: MDS is, as you know, a low-dimensionality mapping method, it could offer insights...